# How to avoid heat problems when using tablets outdoor in high temperatures environments

Tags: tablet, portable, heat-sink

In a very high temperatures region, we are using portable devices (Tablets, IPads) outdoor, which results sometimes in shutting down the device because of heat. Would anybody suggest a specific model of tablets that support high temperatures environments, or a special kind of accessories that would help in solving this problem?

Comment: Can you just put a be quiet fan right next to the back of your ipad and call it a day?

Comment: @Irsu85 - depends on the sun's position. Equatorial sun, not going to make the slightest bit of difference, you will *have* to shade it, both to cool it **and** to read it. [From personal experience; many years in Tenerife.]

Answer (score 0):

The touchscreen will absorb IR heat. Use a hood and get better contrast at the same time but then LED backlight causes heat too, so brightness MUST be reduced with hood.  Even this may be inadequate.

Direct sun on an iPad is like driving the CPU up to 75 W.

Got dry ice bricks?

Answer (score 0):

in outdoor environment do not let the sun impact the device.  Solar radiation will cook it.  Use whatever in order to get the device in the shade.

check out *laptop cooling pads* or *laptop external cooling fans*